# Teams Template with General Posts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to create a Teams Template that contains the General Posts?  I have disclaimers in pinned post in the General channel and I want those to be included in Teams created using this template.  Also, if you open up the Teams in SharePoint, I want the same look and feel when a created from this template.  Is this possible even using Graph?

Comment: You need to Teams template to achieve the above or Graph to customize what you look for?

Answer (score 0):

Copying answer from comments for better understanding.

Teams support the create a Teams Template that contains the General Posts. You need to use Teams template to achieve the above or Graph to customise within teams.